# Dapper and DynamicParameter()

Tags: dapper

I am looking through the code and I am unable to read it. I also tried to find material and examples but I was unable to find specific or any documentation that could help me understand the issue. Can someone read me the code and if there is any documentation to read it.

At first my question is why do we need to use `DynamicParameter()` which is an object of Dapper. I am also not sure what does `=>` means.

```
public void validRecord(string fileName, string rawContent, int userId)
{
    Run(conn => conn.Execute("[dbo].[storedProc_GETDone]"
        , new DynamicParameters
            (new Dictionary<string, object>
                {
                    {"fileName", fileName},
                    {"rowContent", rawContent},
                    {"userCreated", userId},
                }), CommandType.StoredProcedure));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Run` is not part of dapper, but `=>` in C# is used to create a *lambda expression*, in this case I expect it is an `Action<DbConnection>`, i.e. I would guess that your run looks a lot like this:

```
Run(Action<DbConnection> action) {
    using(var conn = CreateConnection()) {
        conn.Open();
        action(conn);
    }
}
```

i.e. it is "I'm going to give you a connection; what do you want to do with it?" - in this case you are choosing to `Execute` a stored procedure.

Now, it is worth noting that in your example there is no benefit in using `DynamicParameters`, since the information is well known - you could just use:

```
Run(conn => conn.Execute("[dbo].[storedProc_GETDone]",
    new { fileName, rawContent, userCreated = userId },
    CommandType.StoredProcedure));
```

which would work just as well. So in answer to "why do we need to use `DynamicParameter` - *you don't* in this scenario. However, in some cases you might - especially if you are building SQL on the fly manually, for example:

```
if(name != null) {
    sql.Append("and Name = @name ");
    args.Add("name", name);
}
```

Comment: Do you have any link or material where I can go and read about DynamicParameter()

Comment: thanks for the answer sir. it is clear.  Can you point me to a good source to study Dapper?

Comment: @user2688063 what exactly would you like? I can add more information, but it helps to know what is unclear (I'm badly placed to judge that)

Comment: what you explained it is easy to follow especially as now I am working through the code. I wanted to have more info in detail about the dapper so I could work with it in different situations. Now I have a new scnario.

Comment: Now I have a new scnario.    I assume if i use the query it will return a dictonary.  The situation is just like the above only the difference is this time i am expecting a single value from a stored procedure  returnValue which is an integer. At first I tried to get the value and assigned it to an int but I am getting an error because the return value is  dictionary.  Can you help me to get a value?

Comment: sorry I am unable to add the code here I will open a new post.

Comment: @MarcGravell No, the intellisense comments for Dapper are not clear at all. Parameters doc comments are missing from dozens of methods and they are confusing and inconsistent where specified.